# WSO2 IS integrating WSO2 APIM using JDBC user store,the sql scripts have error

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I follow this documents to integrating these two products.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

I want to create user in WSO2 IS,then using these user in API-M.
So i change the deployment.toml file

```
[user_store]
type = "database"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/shared_db?useSSL=false"
username = "root"
password = "root"
```

I have change the default db to MySQL.When i change the default user_store to database.
I find there's some problem in sql.
For example:
the table

```
CREATE TABLE UM_USER (
             UM_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             UM_USER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
             UM_USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
             UM_USER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
             UM_SALT_VALUE VARCHAR(31),
             UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
             UM_CHANGED_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
             UM_TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
             PRIMARY KEY (UM_ID, UM_TENANT_ID),
             UNIQUE(UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID)
)ENGINE INNODB;
```

the defualt sql

```
<Property name="SelectUserSQL">SELECT * FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
```

and i check the code org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager#doAuthenticate
I find the code using the index to get data. But it did't consider the field UM_USER_ID.
so it will throw exception.

to resolve this issue. i add some config in this deployment.toml file like below

```
[user_store.properties]
SelectUserSQL = "SELECT UM_USER_ID,UM_USER_NAME,UM_USER_PASSWORD,UM_SALT_VALUE,UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE,UM_CHANGED_TIME,UM_TENANT_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?"
SelectUserSQLCaseInsensitive = "SELECT UM_USER_ID,UM_USER_NAME,UM_USER_PASSWORD,UM_SALT_VALUE,UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE,UM_CHANGED_TIME,UM_TENANT_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE LOWER(UM_USER_NAME)=LOWER(?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?"
```

But when i create user, it also throw exception like

```
[2021-01-20 16:11:03,837] [119a792a-9057-426f-9929-3d68b569247e] ERROR {org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.AbstractResourceManager} - Error in adding the user: kim to the user store. org.wso2.charon3.core.exceptions.CharonException: Error in adding the user: kim to the user store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager.resolveError(SCIMUserManager.java:353)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:325)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceManager.create(UserResourceManager.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:108)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:95)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : kim
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUserWithID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:13819)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMUserManager.createUser(SCIMUserManager.java:287)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:196)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:199)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : kim
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doAddUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1396)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUserWithID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:14089)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while updating string values to database.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1442)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'UM_USER_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor171.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2568)
    ... 74 more
```

When i check the database, i find when i using the defualt configuration

```
[user_store]
    type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
    connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
    connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
    connection_password = "admin"
    base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org"
```

it's ok to create user, the filed um_user_id have set value.

The product version:
WSO2 IS 5.12.0-m6
WSO2 APIM  3.2.0

Comment: can you set user store database type to database_unique_id and check?

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

Comment: great! As per the tip in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/ it seems 'database' user store type is not supported from IS 5.10.0 onwards unless for environments migrated from a lower version. Just adding this info for reference.